# Plotting only parts of vector

Tags: matlab, vector, time, plot

I have a vector like this:

> a = [1 2 0 0 3 4 0 5]

I wanna plot this vector but getting rid of the Os. So, I tried this:

```
> b = (a>0);
> c = a(b);
> plot(c);
```

The plot is just fine bit I'm not happy with the time axis. On the time axis, I have now consecutive steps; but I want it to be the corresponding time steps from `a` to the values `i` plot from `c`. So, in this case, my timeline should look like this:

```
> [1 2 5 6 8]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the undesired values of `a` to `NaN`, and `plot` ignores them and interjects the line where `NaN` occurs.

```
a(a==0)=NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply define a variable with your t and use the filter on it as well

```
a= [1 2 0 0 3 4 0 5]
t = 1:length(a)
idx=(a>0);
plot(t(idx), a(idx));
```

Comment: `idx = a~=0` might be what OP wants.

Comment: Yes, you are still keeping the index logic(logical indexing) that way and you are adhering to OP's requirement of `"get rid of the Os"`. You are assuming `a` doesn't have negative values, which OP might want to keep.

Answer (score 1):

`find()` does exactly what you want, return the index of every nonzero value.

```
a= [1 2 0 0 3 4 0 5];
b=find(a);
plot(b,a(b))
```

If you only want positive values, you also hook that into find:

```
b=find(a>0);
```